# Boolean return in Javascript function

Tags: javascript

Today I am doing a tutorial for hack reactor and this is one of the coding tests.

**Create an isPresent variable,
assign it to a comparison between object's value at key and undefined,
return the isPresent variable**

and this is my code.

```
function isPropertyPresent(object, key) {

  var isPresent = (object['key'] === undefined);
  return isPresent
}
```

I run it line by line in the developer console it's all works fine but whenever I use it in the function it always returns "true", is there any property I didn't notice, I am really confused?

Comment: remove the quotes around `'key'`. ie . `(object[key] === undefined)`

Answer (score 2):

**key** is a variable, so don't put quotes around that and use **!==** operator according to your function name; remove isPresent variable that is unnecessary inside your function, to make code more concise.

```
function isPropertyPresent(object, key) {
  return object[key] !== undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`object['key']` is looking for a property literally named 'key'. You need to look for a property passed in the `key` argument, which is `object[key]`

```js
var objectWithKeyProperty = {
  key: 'secretKey',
  otherProp: 'hello world'
}

var objectWithoutKeyProperty = {
  otherProp: 'hello world'
}

function isPropertyPresentOriginal(object, key) {
  var isPresent = (object['key'] === undefined);
  return isPresent
}

function isPropertyPresentModified(object, key) {
  var isPresent = (object[key] === undefined);
  return isPresent
}

console.log(isPropertyPresentOriginal(objectWithKeyProperty, 'does not matter, this arg is not being used')) // true
console.log(isPropertyPresentOriginal(objectWithoutKeyProperty, 'does not matter, this arg is not being used')) // false

console.log(isPropertyPresentModified(objectWithKeyProperty, 'key')) // true
console.log(isPropertyPresentModified(objectWithoutKeyProperty, 'key')) // false
```